# Summing elements based on threshold

Tags: python, function, loops, sum, slice

I was doing my homework when I encountered this problem:

> Write a function, mysum_bigger_than , that works the same as mysum ,
> except that it takes a first argument that precedes *args . That
> argument indicates the threshold for including an argument in the sum.
> Thus, calling mysum_bigger
> _than(10, 5, 20, 30, 6) would return 50 —because 5 and 6 aren’t greater than 10 . This function should similarly work with any type
> and assumes that all of the arguments are of the same type. Note that '>' and '<' work on many different types in Python, not just on numbers; with strings, lists, and tuples, it refers to their sort order.

**THE PROBLEM WITH THE CODE UNDERNEATH: I can't sum elements which are bigger than threshold value without threshold value itself!**

```
def mysum_bigger_than(*values):
    if not values:
        return values
    output = values[0]
    for value in values[1:]:
        if value < output:
            continue
        else:
            output += value 
    return output

print(mysum_bigger_than(10,5,20,30,6)) #returns 60 instead of 50
print(mysum_bigger_than('mno', 'abc', 'pqr', 'uvw', 'efg', 'xyz')) #returns everything i need with unnecessary 'mno'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your attempt: You use the threshold (`output`) as a starting point of the summation. Another: You check for *bigger and equal than* the threshold. And I think you should actually model your function signature according to this part of the instructions:

> ... except that it takes a first argument that precedes *args ...

So

```
def mysum_bigger_than(threshold, *values):
```

This has the advantage that (1) without providing a `threshold` the function would return an error. And (2) you don't have to separate the threshold from the `values` list in the function definition.

Here's a suggestion:

```
def mysum_bigger_than(threshold, *values):
    summing = False
    result = None
    for value in values:
        if value > threshold:
            if summing:
                result += value
            else:
                result = value
                summing = True
    return result
```

`summing` is a control variable: It's value is `False` as long as the values in `values` are below the threshold. Once the first value is above the threshold it's value is set to `True`. And at the same time the `result` variable gets "properly" initialized and is used afterwards as summation variable. If no value in `values` is above the threshold the function returns `None`, otherwise the required sum.

Here's another suggestion, which is more compact but probably not as efficient (which would only matter for an extremely large `values` list):

```
def mysum_bigger_than(threshold, *values):
    sum_values = [value for value in values if value > threshold]
    if not sum_values:
        return None
    result = sum_values[0]
    for value in sum_values[1:]:
        result += value
    return result
```

The first step filters those values from `values` that meet the requirement of being bigger than the threshold (using a list comprehension). The next step checks if there are actually values that are bigger than the threshold. The function returns `None` if that's not the case. The rest is just summing up over the filtered values, if there are any.

If you're allowed to, you could use some tools from the standard library, `reduce` and `add`:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

def mysum_bigger_than(threshold, *values):
    sum_values = [value for value in values if value > threshold]
    if not sum_values:
        return None
    return reduce(add, sum_values)
```

But I think this is a bit overkill.

(One thing you definitely shouldn't use here is `sum`, because by design it doesn't work for strings.)

Comment: To be frank I don't understand what '*args' means here, I mean, '*' is the thing when we want to add undefined amount of values. 'args' here is just the name for the values?

Comment: @PreacherBaby Yes, you are right. I chose `args` because that was the name used in the instructions. You could as well, as you did in your code, use `values`, which describes the role of the argument much better.

Comment: @PreacherBaby I've just changed `args` to `values`.

Comment: Why do we have to make 'if summing' and not 'summing = True'? How does it know that the 'summing is True' when we made 'if summing' and not 'summing = True"?

Comment: @PreacherBaby You  could use `if summing == True`, or better `if summing is True`,  as well. `if summing` checks the "truthyness" of `summing`, i.e. `bool(summing)`.  As far as I know it's the most _pythonic_ way to use it. But in the end it's just a preference.

Comment: - If I understand it correctly, we use result = None so we wont define it to be a storage for neither int or str types, but something 'neutral', which is depended on user input?

- Could you elaborate me the 'else: result = value, summing = True' statement?

Comment: @PreacherBaby Re `None`: Exactly. The part `result = value; summing = True` is only executed the _first time_ a value is bigger than the threshold. Up until then the value of `result` is `None`. Now `result` is given a proper starting value and `summing = True` makes sure that in the following the `if summing:`  branch is used.

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach:

```py
def mysum_bigger_than(*values):
    if not values:
        return values
    cond = lambda x: x > values[0]
    return sum(filter(cond, values[1:]))
```